# extra characters in output from NSPasteboard in Python script

Tags: python, nspasteboard

My first post…

I am using a python script to get the text from the clipboard on Mac OS X Lion.

I set the clipboard with the following function:

```
def setClip (text):
    pb = NSPasteboard.generalPasteboard()
    pb.clearContents()
    a = NSArray.arrayWithObject_(text)
    return pb.writeObjects_(a)
```

where `text` = "some text"

I retrieve the clipboard with the following:

```
def getClip():
    pb = NSPasteboard.generalPasteboard()
    pbstring = pb.stringForType_(NSString *)dataType
    return pbstring
```

The output is prepended with a "u" with the text surrounded in quotation marks as follows:

```
In [224]: setClip('some text')
Out[224]: True

In [225]: getClip()
Out[225]: "u'some text'"
```

How do I retrieve the text as it was supposedly entered to the clipboard?

I know nothing about NSPasteboard. I found these snippets of code on stackoverflow.

Thanks in advance.

Addendum: my actual code

```
    from AppKit import *
    def setClip (text):
        pb = NSPasteboard.generalPasteboard()
        pb.clearContents()
        a = NSArray.arrayWithObject_(text)
        return pb.writeObjects_(a)

    def getClip():
        pb = NSPasteboard.generalPasteboard()
        pbstring = pb.stringForType_(NSString *)dataType
        return pbstring
```

And this is what happens when I run it in ipython:

The output is prepended with a "u" with the text surrounded in quotation marks as follows:

```
In [224]: setClip('some text')
Out[224]: True

In [225]: getClip()
Out[225]: "u'some text'"
```

***tried a suggestion from the answer******

```
def getClip():
    pb = NSPasteboard.generalPasteboard()
    return pb.stringForType_("public.utf8-plain-text")

In [332]: getClip()
Out[332]: u"some text"
```

No go. :-(

YES. I just needed to do this:

```
print getClip()
```

And I now have

```
"some text"
```

Comment: What happens if you use [dataForType](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSPasteboard_Class/Reference/Reference.html) instead of `stringForType`?

Comment: This can't be your actual code, because the second line of `getClip` will raise a `SyntaxError`. We can't debug your code unless you show us the right code.

Comment: The syntax of `pbstring = pb.stringForType_(NSString *)dataType` looks like it may be from a different language - can you include exactly what you are using to generate the output above?

Comment: @RocketDonkey: It's not actually from a different language—or, rather, it's halfway between PyObjC-style Python and native ObJC, in a way that's a syntax error in either language (and, for that matter, either a syntax error or a useless construct in every language with Cocoa bindings that I've ever heard of).

Comment: @abarnert Interesting, haven't come across PyObjC before (and +1 to your answer).

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am using from AppKit import *

Comment: @RocketDonkey: I'm guessing you don't do any Mac-specific development, or at least not anything that interacts with the higher (Cocoa) levels of the OS rather than just the BSD level. Otherwise, you wouldn't be able to live without it. Anyway, the ObJC method `smalltalkStyle:(NSString *)name withInterspersed:(NSString *)parameters` becomes the Python method `smalltalkStyle_withInterspersed_(name, parameters)`, which is quite ugly, but once you get used to it it's pretty readable, and you can translate between Cocoa docs and Python code without thinking.

Comment: @user1913726: OK, I'll edit my answer to take that into account. But more importantly, please show us your real code!

Comment: Found a related post: http://cl.ly/3z1T0Q2L2b44

Comment: That was my real code. I simply forgot to mention the AppKit module.

Comment: @abarnert Very interesting - looks like another topic to read up on (and you're correct in your assumption - being a non-developer, I am a Windows guy by default :) ).

Comment: This is not your real code. If this were your real code, `getClip()` would not return `"u'some text'"`, it would raise `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` with the caret pointing at the asterisk in the second line.

Comment: @ubuntu I tried dataForType. This is what happened: In [326]: getClip()
Out[326]: '<436f6c6c 65637469 6f6e206f ........[lots more numbers]

Comment: The new version is actually correct! Let me edit my answer to explain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know nothing about NSPasteboard, you should skim the [Pasteboard Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/PasteboardGuide106/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008099), and look at the [NSPasteboard Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/nspasteboard_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for details.

The code you've given us cannot possibly be the code you're running, because:

```
pbstring = pb.stringForType_(NSString *)dataType
```

This is not valid Python. It's somewhere half-way between ObjC and Python. So it'll just raise a `SyntaxError`. And even if I turn it into something sensible:

```
pbstring = pb.stringForType_(dataType)
```

Or, if you want to be explicit:

```
pbstring = pb.stringForType_(NSString.stringWithString_(dataType))
```

This will just be a `NameError`, because you haven't defined `dataType` anywhere.

So, where do you get `dataType` from? Well, the reference for `stringForType:` makes that pretty clear:

> You must send types or availableTypeFromArray: before invoking stringForType:.

So, what if we call `pb.types()`? We get back a list of strings, something like this:

```
Out[153]: 
(
    "NeXT smart paste pasteboard type",
    "com.apple.webarchive",
    "NeXT Rich Text Format v1.0 pasteboard type",
    "public.utf8-plain-text",
    NSStringPboardType,
    …
)
```

A few of the built-in types won't come back as string literals like `u"public.utf8-plain-text", but as string constants from one of the Cocoa libraries, like`NSStringPboardType`. If you've done`from AppKit import *`,`from Cocoa import *`, or similar, you can just refer to it as`NSStringPboardType`.

Anyway pick something that looks reasonable and use it:

```
In [156]: pb.stringForType_(NSStringPboardType)
Out[156]: u'some text'
```

Everything is fine!

So, why are you getting `"u'some text'"` instead of just `u'some text'`? My guess is that, in your real code, either `setClip` or `getClip` is doing an extra `repr(s)` somewhere. For example:

```
In [165]: s=u'some text'

In [166]: repr(s)
Out[166]: "u'some text'"

In [167]: s
Out[167]: u'some text'
```

`Out[166]` may look familiar to you. Most likely, you've done the equivalent in your code. But since you haven't done it in the code you showed us, we can't guess where.

The right way to write `getClip()` is to make a `list` of types in your order of preference, then do something like this:

```
def getClip():
    pb = NSPasteboard.generalPasteboard()
    best_type = pb.availableTypeFromArray_(myFavoriteTypes)
    if best_type:
        return pb.stringForType_(best_type)
```

This may seem like a pain, and unnecessary. Can't you just do `return pb.stringForType_(best_type[0])` and skip that whole `availableTypeFromArray_` nonsense? In practice, if the type you want is NSStringPboardType, you will get away with it with every version of OS X so far, with probably every program in the universe, because it just doesn't make sense to put text on the clipboard and not make it available in that format. But it's still wrong, and a bad habit to get into. (Besides, maybe you'd actually *prefer* to get UTF-8 bytes instead of a Unicode string, which may be easier to deal with in Python 2.x, or more efficient in 3.3.)

When you do things right, if you just type `getClip()` at the console, you will see `u'some text'` instead of `'u"some text"'`. "But hold on", you say, "there's still a 'u' and a pair of quotes there, even if there aren't two pairs of quotes anymore, so it's still broken!" No, it's not. Take a look at this:

```
In [182]: s=u'some text'

In [183]: s
Out[183]: u'some text'

In [184]: print s
some text
```

Or this:

```
In [185]: s='some text'

In [186]: s
Out[186]: 'some text'

In [187]: print s
some text
```

Whenever you just type a string (or a function that returns a string) at the interactive console, it prints out the string with quotes. But the quotes aren't actually in the string—as you can see when you use the `print` statement explicitly.

So, if you see this:

```
In [332]: getClip()
Out[332]: u"some text"
```

That's actually correct. It's the same as the `s=u'some text'` example above. There are no quotes, or `u` characters, in your string; that's just the way the interactive interpreter shows strings that you type at the command line. To verify it, just `print` the result:

```
In [332]: print getClip()
some text
```

Or store it in a file:

```
In [188]: with open('test.txt', 'w') as f:
   .....:     f.write(getClip())
   .....:
```

Now open `test.txt` in your text editor—no quotes, no `u`.

Comment: Apparently, as mentioned in this post, http://cl.ly/3z1T0Q2L2b44, I just have to "suck it up" when it comes to the prepended 'u'.

Comment: @user1913726: No, that's not your actual problem. The `repr` of the string does have the prepended 'u', but even without that, you have the extra quotes. Your problem is that you have the `repr` of the string instead of just the string itself, and that's what you need to fix.

Comment: I just want to grab the text from my clipboard and use python to process it. I just don't have the time to dive into NSPasteboard right now since my main objective is to work on python. Thank you for the help.

Comment: I did a workaround that I know how to do at my level of very rudimentary scripting. I write the output to a tmp file, read that file into a variable, and then do my text processing accounting for the extra 'u"' at the beginning.

Comment: @user1913726: I gave you the correct code in my answer. Just copy and paste that. Either that, or show us your actual code so we can tell you what's wrong with it.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to use my clipboard as my text source. I am copying text from the kindle app, and I want to remove all the extras that the kindle app adds to it.

Comment: I know absolutely nothing about NSPasteboard. The defs I posted in my question are just black boxes that I am using to achieve my goal. I somewhat follow your answer, but it's all still a black box to me.

Comment: I tried something from what you suggested, but the 'u' is still there. I added it to the end of my question. Thanks for trying.

Comment: Again, the defs you posted in your definition cannot possibly be the actual code that you're running. And I don't know what "Unfortunately, I have to use my clipboard as my text source" is supposed to mean, because my answer tells you exactly how to do exactly that, and all you have to do is copy and paste it. If that's too hard for you to figure out, I don't know what to tell you.

Comment: Hold on, in your new edit, you got the right answer this time. Let me edit my answer to explain.

Comment: That is my actual code. I am pasting it into my terminal and running it in ipython.

Comment: My issue is that prefixed 'u'. My issue was not getting something from the clipboard. I am just not getting what I expected or wanted.

Comment: SOLVED! Thank you so much. I just need to use "print getClip()" and the "u" goes away. Thanks for clarifying that I needed to specify a datatype.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. I jumped in without thoroughly RTFM.